# How to handle skipWaiting and lazyloaded resources

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

So this is something I've been racking my brain about a bit, consider the following scenario:

I'm working on my project, I build it, and in my bundle is a lazyloaded module: `module-a-[oldhash].js`, that will get lazyloaded at some point in time.

Everything is fine and dandy.

I do some more work on my project, create a new bundle, deploy, and now my content hash has changed: `module-a-[newhash].js`. I deploy, go to my page, my service worker calls skipWaiting, but my page still tries to request `module-a-[oldhash].js`, which now no longer exists.

How do I go about this? The only way that I can think of handling this, is show an 'update available' message that posts a skipWaiting message to the service worker, and reloads the page on `controllerchange` event. But I'm curious if theres no way to achieve to same thing without having to include such a notification/toast pattern and a reload.

Additionally, its my understanding that this would only pose a problem with lazyloaded resources

Is my understanding of these problems correct? What are some common patterns for dealing with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much everything you describe there is correct. I'll just point out that this is a problem that extends beyond the use of a service worker. It can easily happen with long-lived single page apps that attempt to lazy-load a URL that has been replaced server-side with a new deployment.

There's some general information about the problem and potential solutions collected on at this [Paying Attention while Loading Lazily](https://pawll.glitch.me/) site and associated video.

In general, the best practice is to:

- *Always* assume that lazy-loading might fail (for whatever reason) and handle those failures gracefully. One approach might be to ask a user to reload the page upon encountering a failure.
- Using a cache-first service worker can help protect against lazy-loading failures, at the expense of delaying updates until the newly installed service worker moves from `waiting` to `active`. As you mentioned, the best practice tends to be to show something in your UI letting a user know that updates are available, and once they opt-in to accepting those updates, `postMessage()` to the service worker telling it to call `skipWaiting()`. And finally, listening for the `controllerchange` event and calling `window.location.reload()` when that's fired.